# How do I make a kill counter in MCBE without using XP?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

How do I make a kill counter in mcpe without using XP?

The problem is, if there are 2 or more players on my server, if I snipe a player across the map, the nearest player from the player I sniped gets the kill instead of me. What commands can I use?

Comment: Please see [What to do before asking a minecraft-commands question?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13507/4797)

Comment: Have you tried using a scoreboard?

Comment: @FTL'saccountwillbedeleted I dont think mcbe scoreboard can do that, only java

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in the Bedrock version of the game, as the closest you can get is what you seemed like you used, an @p. You could do something where you tag whoever is in a block radius of the arrow and then figure out who died and who is still alive but it would be buggy and more trouble than its worth.